# Get user's location on background service using FusedLocationProviderApi & Google Places API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

My current code use `FusedLocationProviderApi` to get user's current city/locality. This code is in my `Service` :

```
                try {
                    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(LocationUpdateService.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    if (addresses.size() > 0)
                    {
                        txtStation.setText("Locality : " + addresses.get(0).getLocality() + " Sublocal : " + addresses.get(0).getSubLocality());
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(LocationUpdateService.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

However i need to show user's **more specific place** (bus station, gas station, etc) and i think i must use `Places API`.

How to integrate the `Places API` to my current code (which use `FusedLocationProviderApi`)?

What i think now is to use `FusedLocationProviderApi` to get the basic `latitude` & `longitude`, and then use `Places API` with those coordinates.

Please kindly help me/show me some clue

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the [PlaceDetectionApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceDetectionApi)?

Comment: Thanks for the clue. My code currently using `FusedLocationProviderApi` to check user's current location. Should i replace the code? Or can i integrate both of the APIs?

Comment: For a specific place, rather than a lat/long, use just `PlaceDetectionApi`.

Comment: I think that you can replace the code.  `getCurrentPlace` will do the geolocating for you.

Comment: Yes, it seems i dont need to care about lat/lang. The `PlacesAPI` do the work :) Thanks a lot